# Переход в настройки батареи Swift

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть приложение при запуске которого я проверяю включен ли у меня режим энергосбережения, если да я вызываю Alert и предлагаю его выключить! Если пользователь соглашается то я должен открывать настройки батареи.
Проверку на энергосбережение я сделал а открытие настроек батареи не получается, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 5):

Начиная с iOS 11 разрешено открыть программно только настройки своего приложения.

Плюс, если Вы все же сделаете это для прошлых версий (App-prefs:root=...), то с большой вероятностью приложение будет отклонено с формулировкой:

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme

Можете пользователю предложить перейти в нужный пункт меню настроек и показать инструкцию как именно.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

> Targets -> Ваше приложение -> Info -> URL Types -> +

В поле `URL Schemes` добавьте `prefs`

Для вызова:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "App-prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE")!)
```

Вот тут можете посмотреть доступные [URL Schemes](https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560#url-schemes)